# Telegram Bot on Heroku, App URL cannot be found

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

I am trying to host a telegram bot on Heroku. I have deployed this at `main` for now. This is my first time working on Heroku and I guess I am messing up on this step. When I run this command.
`git push heroku master`

I get

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/abhisjokebot.git'
```

I am guessing this is the reason why I get 404 Not Found for my app, Though all the other info seems correct.

```
user.email= my email
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.heroku.url=git@heroku.com:abhisjokebot.git #Correct
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

This is the error when I send `/start` to my bot.

```
updater.bot.setWebhook('https://abhisjokebot.herokuapp.com' + TOKEN)
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in set_webhook
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 70, in decorator
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714945+00:00 app[web.1]: result = func(*args, **kwargs)
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714951+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 2240, in set_webhook
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714952+00:00 app[web.1]: result = self._request.post(url_, data, timeout=timeout)
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 334, in post
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714957+00:00 app[web.1]: **urlopen_kwargs)
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714961+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 245, in _request_wrapper
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714962+00:00 app[web.1]: raise BadRequest(message)
2021-01-02T13:06:32.714962+00:00 app[web.1]: telegram.error.BadRequest: Bad webhook: failed to resolve host: name or service not known
```

I am using this as webhook. Port is set to 5000

```
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=int(PORT),
                          url_path=TOKEN)
updater.bot.setWebhook('https://abhisjokebot.herokuapp.com' + TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a fwd slash before the `TOKEN`

```
updater.bot.setWebhook('https://abhisjokebot.herokuapp.com/' + TOKEN)
```

The git push is a different problem, it seems you cannot push changes (did you commit latest changes?). You can try to recreate your git repo again.

Comment: I solved all the issues, finally and answered my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542494/issues-with-telegram-bot-app-when-deploying-on-heroku  Thanks for your input.