# Issues with telegram bot app when deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I have been trying to deploy a python app to heroku. I keep getting the 404 not found error on the app link page. When my code tries to access it I see this error. For now I have enabled the maintenance mode.

```
2021-01-02T18:02:57.797663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=abhijokebot.herokuapp.com request_id=aa8f297b-5251-40cc-ba55-897a446a14f3 fwd="106.215.49.148" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=238 protocol=https

2021-01-02T18:02:58.205536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abhijokebot.herokuapp.com request_id=50704ce5-fda7-48d3-9024-b1a8c87dd15a fwd="106.215.49.148" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=238 protocol=https

2021-01-02T18:12:42.433792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=abhijokebot.herokuapp.com request_id=1ea7b738-7d8a-4a3e-91f9-28e1c74a948a fwd="54.162.178.132" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=238 protocol=http

2021-01-02T18:18:15.610626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=abhijokebot.herokuapp.com request_id=e93624c5-d9bb-4236-82d0-44c2134fbace fwd="116.202.35.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=238 protocol=http

2021-01-02T18:18:15.836002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=abhijokebot.herokuapp.com request_id=cc548c62-d5a0-47ab-91e2-c7ebfc630070 fwd="116.202.35.94" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=238 protocol=http
```

This is a telegram bot, so I am not really sure what I am supposed to see at my app link page, However, everything points to app running successfully. I am guessing I don't have the default path for the app set. I looked everywhere but couldn't find any such settings in Heroku. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to go through many many answers and articles to figure this one out. So, I hope I am saving a lot of hard work to any future visitors here (Newbies on Heroku, not Experts)
Well, The first problem with any application on Heroku is that they assign a port or you choose a default one. In 99% of the cases this will solve it for you.

```
PORT = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 13978))
```

Just do not use a common port, is my guess. This got my code finally ONLINE. Otherwise, I had this.

```
PORT = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
```

Now, this is just for the telegram-bot people.
This is the working e.g as of today

```
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=PORT,
                          url_path=TOKEN)
    updater.bot.setWebhook('https://myapp.herokuapp.com/' + TOKEN)
```

Exactly like it is. I wasted another 20 minutes on `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/TOKEN'`.
That will not work.
Always remember, now, this is very easy to forget. If you are using packages which need a `path` you need to set `PATHS` for them. I did it in the webapp, doesn't work.
After setting the `AddBuildpack` option in the Heroku>app>settings> I did this. These are the two build packs you need to add for selenium.

`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome`

`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver`

**Always prefer the cli commands**

For e.g I was using `selenium` set the `PATH` like this

```
heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google_chrome
heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
```

In the terminal.

In the python code, do like this.

```
 options1 = Options()
 options1.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')
 options1.add_argument("--headless")
 options1.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 options1.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')),options=options1)
```

Of course import `chrome.Options` for this.
`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

Well, This takes care of the problems newbies might face. Happy Coding. Thanks.